# "was the first to" VS "is the first"

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, grammaticality-in-context

1. One Shenzhen Bay **was** the first urban complex to *be built* in Shenzhen.
2. One Shenzhen Bay **is** the first urban complex to *be built* in Shenzhen.
3. One Shenzhen Bay **is** the first urban complex to *have been* built in Shenzhen.

Are the three sentence all grammatical and convey the same meaning?

Comment: To supplement @KateBunting's comment: as soon as a second urban complex is built in Shenzhen, then you would have to stop using sentences 2 and 3. Only sentence 1 would be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Sentence (1) will remain true, however many more urban complexes may be built in Shenzhen in the future.

Sentence (2) can be used while the building is taking place or soon after completion.

Sentence (3) can be used soon after completion of the project. If another urban complex is built, (2) and (3) will no longer be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence (1) makes use of "was...to be built", which shows how it *was* the first building and *will always be*.

Sentence (2) makes use of present tense (**is**), so it *cannot* be used when another urban complex is built in Shenzhen, and can be used during the building or right after the completion of the build (*usually the latter*)

Sentence (3) makes use of present tense (**is**) and takes the past tense of *after the building was complete* (**have been**), and again, *cannot* be used when another urban complex is built in Shenzhen.

Answer (score 0):

English is a crazy language. All the given sentences are grammatically correct.

> 1. *One Shenzhen Bay was the first urban complex to be built in Shenzhen.*

Here, it means that the building of the urban complex happened a long time ago, but it is still the first urban complex that was built in Shenzhen.

> 2. *One Shenzhen Bay is the first urban complex to be built in Shenzhen.*

It is not grammatically incorrect to use present tense here. It may also imply that the urban complex still exists.

> 3. *One Shenzhen Bay is the first urban complex to have been built in Shenzhen.*

Here, using the perfect infinitive is also okay. The sentence means : *'One Shenzhen Bay is the first urban complex that **had been** built in Shenzhen.*

Answer (score 0):

Second and third expressions are identical. First one is different from the other two, as it conveys the idea that the bay is no longer operational and has been demolished.